# Copilot stuck at activating

Tags: github, github-copilot

I am currently connected to my school server through SSH and school VPN.

I am using VS Code with the following details:

```
Version: 1.78.1 (user setup)
Commit: 6a995c4f4cc2ced6e3237749973982e751cb0bf9
Date: 2023-05-04T09:48:08.683Z
Electron: 22.5.1
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
Sandboxed: No
```

I have tried to install GitHub Copilot (locally) and GitHub Copilot Nightly (On SSH) respectively. But none of them worked, it shows that they are undergoing 'activating' forever.

Copilot works fine if I use a local workspace but it is working when I SSH connect to a server.

The output log is empty for Github Copilot.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved.
It was because I opened a workspace at the root directory of my server which contains all the files.
The activation of Copilot requires Pylance to function correctly first. Pylance was not activated correctly because of the workspace.
To solve the problem, change the workspace to a directory that contains few files.

Comment: Good catch’ well done.  Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [VSCode Remote SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh), make sure to check out [discussions 50328](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/50328) which is about a non-working GitHub Copilot extension in this context.

> - Ensure that you have installed and enabled the GitHub Copilot extension on both your local and remote machines.
> - I removed `rm -rf .vscode-server` on remote server and removed all plugins on remote. Then logged in fresh with VS-code and installed minimal set of plugins needed. It is all fine now